# plt.savefig shows different images on google colab in respect to local saves of the same code

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, google-colaboratory, porting

I'm saving the output of a transform which generates 2D images starting from 1D signals.
The code works on google colab and now I'm porting it into local python code. The issue arises when I use the transform to generate the same image, using the same code, starting from the same 1D signal. The outputs are the following:
[image: from ubuntu]
[image: from G colab]

The images are (496, 369) the first and (334, 217) the second. I resized the first and divided them, hoping that the difference was due to a constant factor of some sort, but that's not the case.

Do you know possible something which i may be missing on the first image, maybe done automatically by the library, to generate the second one from the first one?

The library I'm using is https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy
The imshow function of the lib is at https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/visuals.py

While the code I'm using on colab and locally is:

```
def get_spectrum(file_name):

x = np.empty(0)
y = np.empty(0)   


with open(file_name , 'r') as fp:

    for line in fp:

        x_,y_ = line.replace(",",".").split()

        x = np.append(x,float(x_))
        y = np.append(y,float(y_))
        
        sample = np.stack((x,y))

    return sample


def get_image(spectrum, save_name='temp'):

    wavelet = "gmw"
    nv = 64
    scales = 'log'
    abs = True
    pad_width = [[0,0]]
    norm = (0,2)

    [x,y] = spectrum

    kw = dict(wavelet=wavelet, nv=nv, scales=scales)

    pkw = dict(abs=abs)

    Tx, *_ = ssq_cwt(y, **kw)

    _Tx = np.pad(Tx, pad_width = pad_width)  # improve display of top- & bottom-most freqs?
    
    norm = (0, np.abs(Tx).max()/norm[1])

    imshow(_Tx, norm=norm, borders=False, ticks=False,show=False,**pkw)

    plt.savefig("test_IMG/test.png",bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.0,dpi='figure')


get_image(get_spectrum("A1_7664.txt"))
```

EDIT: In the end, using two different versions of matplotlib generates different outputs, even if everything else ( inputs and other parameters ) remains the same.

Comment: looks like different colormaps

Comment: Could you please check which version of matplotlib you are using in your google colab notebook and onto your local machine? You may simply `import matplotlib as mpl` and then execute `print(mpl.__version__)`.

Comment: Locally I'm using the 3.6.2, while on colab 3.2.2! That's the right answer, thank you. Installing the 3.2.2 it gives the same output